# Creating UserControls with ViewModels in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, wpf-controls

do you think is a good practise to create a UserControl already with a ViewModel and deploy both together? This way the UserControl will be binded to the ViewModel from stock.

Looks as a good idea to me but I never saw such a thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing you should be careful of with this approach is that you want to keep your datacontext open and available for binding to in controls where you are using this control.

If you block the data context it'll make it so any bindings you do to the control later will have to have a source specified.

Comment: I would create properties in the ViewModel for the binded properties and when someone wants to change one property of the control (like some subcontrol enabled) he will have to go thru the View Model.

Answer (score 1):

I personally see nothing bad in this idea. For a sufficiently complex UserControl, a ViewModel is anyway needed. I would however make it (VM) as extensible as possible.

Indeed, I've seen some VMs shipped together with controls -- in Swing (Java). For example, [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) serves indeed as a kind of VM for [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html). [But without real bindings Swing's VMs are quite weak.]